# When making a colorscheme, what is the label for the ~ area of the screen below EOF?

Tags: colorscheme

I have found some color schemes that I like, but some of them have the feature that the lines below the content of the file on the display - the `~` area - have a different background color as shown.. I want it to be the same background color as normal text. When editing the color scheme, what keyword am I looking for to fix this?

I'm using MacVim but I assume this is a universal question.

[image: Two different backgrounds]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Vim 8 there is the `EndOfBuffer` highlight group for this; from [`:help hl-EndOfBuffer`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl%2dEndOfBuffer):

```
EndOfBuffer filler lines (~) after the last line in the buffer.
        By default, this is highlighted like hl-NonText.
```

---

For earlier Vim versions it's `NonText`. From [`:help hl-NonText`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-NonText):

```
NonText         '~' and '@' at the end of the window, characters from
                'showbreak' and other characters that do not really exist in
                the text (e.g., ">" displayed when a double-wide character
                doesn't fit at the end of the line).
```

---

I didn't know this either. How I found this:

- I typed [`:help 'highlight'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27hl%27)
- I noticed there's a list with highlight "occasions" here with a brief description.
- Type `/\~` to search for the `~` character

And on [`:help colorscheme`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#E185) I read:

```
:hi[ghlight] clear {group-name}
:hi[ghlight] {group-name} NONE
                        Disable the highlighting for one highlight group.  It
                        is _not_ set back to the default colors.
```

Using `:highlight clear NonText` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of highlight groups, I believe it is called `NonText`. From [`:he highlight-groups`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-NonText):

```
                                                        hl-NonText
NonText         '~' and '@' at the end of the window, characters from
                'showbreak' and other characters that do not really exist in
                the text (e.g., ">" displayed when a double-wide character
                doesn't fit at the end of the line).
```

You can probably set it to the same colour as the remaining area using:

```
:hi NonText ctermfg=NONE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `NonText` was what I needed. I found the snippet didn't work, though `hi NonText ctermbg=NONE` did as per @Carpetsmoker's answer.

Comment: @Coljac I'm confused. Isn't that exactly what I have written?

Comment: Apologies for the cut and paste error. It was `:highlight clear NonText` that worked (from vim) - though knowing "NonText" I was able to edit the colorscheme easily enough.

Comment: @Coljac Muru's example had a minor typo: it was `ctermbg`, but should be `ctermfg` (I've fixed this now).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker if that works, colour me surprised. I thought `fg` applied to the text.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think `bg` is correct. I think more likely the problem with muru's code is that the OP is probably using MacVim's GUI, so should be setting `guibg`